# How to deploy two build react apps in the same domain with .htaccess

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two build vite react apps.

I am going to deploy these in the same domain.

For example if the request URL is "https://example.com/admin/*" I should show app1 and for other URLs I should show app2.

So I configed .htaccess file like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    # For URIs starting with /admin, load the app in admin directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.html [L]

    # For all other URIs, load the app in html directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I am using nginx and nginx config file is like this.

```
        root /var/www;
        location / {
            try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ /html/index.html;
         }
```

The app1 is in  `/var/www/html/admin` directory and the app2 is in `var/www/html` directory.

But I got the 404 error for `/admin/*` URL.

How to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the 404 error you're encountering when accessing URLs starting with /admin/*, you need to adjust your **Nginx configuration**. Here's an updated configuration that should resolve the issue:

```
root /var/www;

location /admin {
    alias /var/www/html/admin;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

In the updated configuration:

- The **/admin** location block handles requests for URLs starting with /admin. It uses the alias directive to specify the correct directory path for the app1 located in /var/www/html/admin. The try_files directive is used to check if the requested URI exists as a file or a directory. If not, it will serve /admin/index.html, which is the entry point for app1.
- The **/** location block handles requests for all other URLs. The try_files directive checks if the requested URI exists as a file, with .html appended to it, as a directory, or else serves /index.html, which is the entry point for app2.

By updating your Nginx configuration as shown above, you should be able to correctly route requests to the respective applications based on the URL path.

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with this answer, I would encourage you to delete it. **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as it may contain fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. [Posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831), and the moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 2):

Using htaccess with nginx is usually not a good idea (see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/): "You can’t do this. You shouldn’t. If you need .htaccess, you’re probably doing it wrong.").
You can easily achieve the desired result by adding:

```
root /path/to/your/root/directory;

location /admin/ {
    alias /path/to/app1/build/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location / {
    alias /path/to/app2/build/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

to your nginx config file. You can also use [htaccess to nginx converter](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess)
if you have any other htacess rules that you wanna port to nginx.

Comment: I tried like this.
But I got error like this one for ``/admin`` path.
``Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.``

Answer (score 1):

I solved this like this.

I edited the nginx config file like this.

```
      location /admin/ {
               alias /var/www/html/admin/;
               try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
       }

        location / {
            root /var/www/html/;
            try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ /index.html;
         }
```

And when I build the admin react app I added the base suburl with this command.

```
vite build --base=/admin/
```